# Auto scrolling vertical list?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

In my air app I have a list(vertical) on the left side, like a sidebar. It`s working fine! The things is I want to put some animation in this list, which all the times when I select one item all the list moves, and this item goes to the center of the list!
Someone have same example or URL, or something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar using the **AnimateProperty** effect to animate the scrolling of a list to a given index.

See my blog post here:
http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2011/01/animated-scrolling-list.html